# Using touch events in cordova windos app

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, microsoft-edge, touchstart

I am creating an application for windows using cordova that heavily relies on touch events such as `touchstart` and `touchmove`. These events work fine in the android and iOS version but they are not fired in the windows version. Instead the browser tries to scroll the page on touches (note: I am calling the `event.preventDefault` function on `touchstart`. but the event doesn't even fire).

In this case the edge browser has the same behaviour as the cordova app. In edge the is an option when u navigate to `about:flags` called `enable touch events` when this flag is set to `Always on` or `Only on when a touchscreen is detected` the application works perfectly. I was wondering if it is plausible to set this flag in the cordova application.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any news? I'm facing the same problem. As far as I can see, there is *no* event firing that could replace touchmove either. Without setting the flag I get *one* mousemove event (when using touch), but it's only called once when moving around, it's not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later, facing the same issue and found a solution by setting this in the CSS :

```
body { touch-action:none; }
```

I've also managed to make a jQuery slider inside an iframe in a Cordova App work correctly in tablet mode by using :

```
iframe { touch-action:none; }
```